# Liquidsoap not identifying variable clearly defined

Tags: audio, stream, audio-streaming, icecast, liquidsoap

Alright, I've been puling my hair out for hours

Liquidsoap just isn't working for me, and I know this should work, sub for one appearently obvious error...

```
set("log.file",false)
set("log.stdout",true)
set("log.level",3)

podcasts = playlist("/home/user/icecast/ham.txt")

# This function turns a fallible
# source into an infallible source
# by playing a static single when
# the original song is not available
def my_safe(radio) =
  # We assume that festival is installed and
  # functional in liquidsoap
  security = single("say:Hello, we are currently having some technical difficulties but we'll be back soon so stay tuned!")
  # We return a fallback where the original
  # source has priority over the security
  # single. We set track_sensitive to false
  # to return immediately to the original source
  # when it becomes available again.
  fallback(track_sensitive=false,[radio, security])
end

radio= podcasts
radio= my_safe(podcasts)

# A function that contains all the output
# we want to create with the final stream
def outputs(s) =
  # First, we partially apply output.icecast
  # with common parameters. The resulting function
  # is stored in a new definition of output.icecast,
  # but this could be my_icecast or anything.
  output.icecast = output.icecast(host="localhost", password="foobar")
  # An output in mp3 to the "live" mountpoint:
  output.icecast(%mp3, mount="live",radio)
end
```

And the error

```
At line 23, character 6: The variable radio defined here is not used anywhere
  in its scope. Use ignore(...) instead of radio = ... if you meant
  to not use it. Otherwise, this may be a typo or a sign that your script
  does not do what you intend.
```

If someone could also fix another issue I'm having

I would like to find how to run two sources to two separate mountpoints

```
set("log.file",false)
set("log.stdout",true)
set("log.level",3)

podcasts = playlist("/home/user/icecast/ham.txt")
songlist = playlist("/home/user/icecast/otherplaylist.txt")

# This function turns a fallible
# source into an infallible source
# by playing a static single when
# the original song is not available
def my_safe(radio) =
  # We assume that festival is installed and
  # functional in liquidsoap
  security = single("say:Hello, we are currently having some technical difficulties but we'll be back soon so stay tuned!")
  # We return a fallback where the original
  # source has priority over the security
  # single. We set track_sensitive to false
  # to return immediately to the original source
  # when it becomes available again.
  fallback(track_sensitive=false,[radio, security])
end

radio= podcasts
radio= my_safe(podcasts)

def my_safe(songlist) =
  # We assume that festival is installed and
  # functional in liquidsoap
  security = single("say:Hello, we are currently having some technical difficulties but we'll be back soon so stay tuned!")
  # We return a fallback where the original
  # source has priority over the security
  # single. We set track_sensitive to false
  # to return immediately to the original source
  # when it becomes available again.
  fallback(track_sensitive=false,[songlist, security])
end

moarradio= songlist
moarradio= my_safe(songlist)

# A function that contains all the output
# we want to create with the final stream
def outputs(s) =
  # First, we partially apply output.icecast
  # with common parameters. The resulting function
  # is stored in a new definition of output.icecast,
  # but this could be my_icecast or anything.
  output.icecast = output.icecast(host="localhost", password="foobar")
  # An output in mp3 to the "live" mountpoint:
  output.icecast(%mp3, mount="live",radio)

  output.icecast(%mp3, mount="otherlive",moarmusic)
end
```

And I get the same error, but it tells me the second variable isn't used (moarradio)

Answer (score 3):

The `liquidsoap` configuration file is basically a script, which means it will be run from top to bottom.

Upon reading the configuration file, it is complaining that you are not using the `radio` variable defined line 23, the reason being you are using the one defined line 24. Unlike many other languages, there are [no assignments, only definitions](http://www.liquidsoap.info/doc-dev/language.html) in a liquidsoap script

Other than that, you seem to not understand the difference between global and local variables, and their respective scopes.

You are declaring a `my_safe` function, which takes an argument. Within the scope of the function, refer to your argument with its name. Then call the `my_safe` function with your global variables as the argument, and what you are expecting will actually happen.

Your sources will not get registered if you do not call the `outputs` function. Simply drop the function construct.

Here is how I rewrote your second example:

```
set("log.file",false)
set("log.stdout",true)
set("log.level",3)

podcasts = playlist("/home/user/icecast/ham.txt")
songlist = playlist("/home/user/icecast/otherplaylist.txt")

# This function turns a fallible
# source into an infallible source
# by playing a static single when
# the original song is not available
def my_safe(stream) =                          # <- used a different variable name here
  # We assume that festival is installed and
  # functional in liquidsoap
  security = single("say:Hello, we are currently having some technical difficulties but we'll be back soon so stay tuned!")
  # We return a fallback where the original
  # source has priority over the security
  # single. We set track_sensitive to false
  # to return immediately to the original source
  # when it becomes available again.
  fallback(track_sensitive=false,[stream, security])  # <- used a different variable name here
end

radio= my_safe(podcasts) # <- fix here

# <- got rid of redeclaration of my_safe

moarradio= my_safe(songlist) # <- fix here

# <- got rid of function construct
# First, we partially apply output.icecast
# with common parameters. The resulting function
# is stored in a new definition of output.icecast,
# but this could be my_icecast or anything.
output.icecast = output.icecast(host="localhost", password="foobar")
# An output in mp3 to the "live" mountpoint:
output.icecast(%mp3, mount="live",radio)
output.icecast(%mp3, mount="otherlive",moarradio)  # <- fix here
```